# Subquery factoring: Inner Join with each other

Tags: oracle, view, oracle11g, subquery-factoring

I have four WITH clauses.  I wanted to know if it is possible to use inner joins among them.

I searched on the net and i could not find anything related to this.

Oracle version: 11g

** EDIT **

```
WITH
    GETDATABYDAY AS
    (
        select column1, column2
        from table1 
        where sales > 2000
     )
    SELECT
      column1,
      column2
    FROM
      GETDATABYDAY;

WITH
    GETDATABYDAY1 AS
    (
        select column3, column2
        from table1 
        where date between 'date1' and 'date2'
    )
    SELECT
        column3,
        column2
    FROM
        GETDATABYDAY1;

Assume that there are two more WITH named: GETDATABYDAY2 and GETDATABYDAY3
```

Is it possible to use inner join on all GETDATABYDAY, GETDATABYDAY1, GETDATABYDAY2 and GETDATABYDAY3?

Comment: @A.B.Cade because i do not want to take any risk

Comment: Start by trying **2** WITH clauses, with very simple SQL.

Comment: Then I'll be the brave one! here is a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/765 . Is this what you mean ?

Comment: Where is the "risk" in running e.g. `with a as (select * from emp), b as (select * from dept) select * from a join b on b.deptno = a.deptno;`?

Comment: @TonyAndrews is it feasible? this is my question

Comment: @TonyAndrews no not like this. 4 different WITH clauses!

Comment: OK, so add 2 more WITHs and try it again.  You can't break anything with a select statement!

Comment: What do you mean 4 different `with clauses` ?

Comment: 5 withs will definitely break your machines

Comment: @BobJarvis sample code posted

Comment: And how would you propose to join these together?  That is, what's common between them that could be used as join criteria?  You could do a natural join, where all rows from each query are joined with all rows from all the other queries, but I doubt that's what you really want.  Is there a key on TABLE1 which could be used to match rows up?

Comment: @BobJarvis Assume anything you want to make the join possible

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will work:

```
with first_cte as ( 
    select ...
    from ...
), second_cte as (
    select ...
    from first_cte
      join some_table on ...
), third_cte as (
    select ...
    from ...
) fourth_cte as (
    select ...
    from some_other_table
      join second_cte on ...
) 
select ..
from fourth_cte
   join third_cte on ....
```

Comment: @sameer: when using multiple WITH clauses you only have the keyword **once** and there is no `;` between them. Compare my example with your code.

Comment: i am not saying a single WITH clause.. I have more than one WITH clause! will it be possible to inner join??

Your code is only with one WITH clause

Comment: @sameer: no, there are four common table expressions (which is the correct name for a "with clause") in my statement. The *keyword* WITH may only appear once, but multiple CTEs are allowed (and they are inner joined on various levels in my statement)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can work, since every `with clause`  is part of a whole different query.

You can create `db views` though, and use them instead of the with clause.